# Constrain Violation Exceptions

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, neo4j, c#-3.0, neo4jclient

My code is below,  Is there a better way to write this query so that we do not get constraint violation exceptions? seeing as we have a unique constraint on :SiteEntry(Url) and errors = exceptions

Code:

```
                        GraphRepository.WriteClient.Cypher
                        .With("{uris} as links")
                        .Unwind("links", "link")
                        .Merge("(site:SiteEntry:InNetwork{Url:{url},SiteTitle:{st}})")
                        .Merge("(s2:SiteEntry{Url:link.Url})")
                        .With("site,s2,link")
                        //next line formerly createunique 
                        .Merge("(site)-[:LinksTo{AnchorText:link.AnchorText}]->(s2)")
                        .WithParams(
                            new {url = uriResponse.Url, uris = uriResponse.OutLinks, st = uriResponse.SiteTitle})
                        .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync()
```

Thanks

Comment: What are the  errors?  Do the errors occur during run time or compile time?

Comment: Posting the errors would help us. By the way the semicolon is not necessary for the statements through the cypher http transactional endpoint

Comment: Is there a better way to write this query so that we do not get constraint violation exceptions? 

I have updated the question to be more accurate

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not provide enough information to totally understand your situation, but here is some information that might help.

If your DB has a *uniqueness constraint* or *index* (which automatically creates a uniqueness constraint), then a node `MERGE` that involves such a constraint will cause a constraint violation if: (a) the DB does not have a node with ALL of the specified properties, but (b) it does have a node with SOME of the specified properties -- and those include constrained properties. In this situation, the `MERGE` can neither return an existing node, nor create a new one without violating a uniqueness constraint.

For example, suppose your DB has a uniqueness constraint and node defined this way:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:SiteEntry) ASSERT s.Url IS UNIQUE;

CREATE (s:SiteEntry { Url: "http://stackoverflow.com" });
```

Then, the following query would create a constraint violation. Although there is no completely matching node, the uniqueness constraint prevents the `MERGE` from creating a new node:

```
MERGE (s:SiteEntry { Url: "http://stackoverflow.com", SiteTitle:"SO" })
```

(By the way, a uniqueness constraint is not violated if `MERGE` adds a new label to an otherwise matching node.)